# In ejabberd, mod_http_upload returns "ignoring listen option 'request_handlers' with invalid value: [{upload,mod_http_upload}]"

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

In ejabberd 18.01-2, installed in lxc container Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic LTS using `apt`, I'm trying to setup `mod_http_upload`.

Following the [documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-http-upload), in the section `listen`, I have

```
listen:
  ...
  -
    port: 5443
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      upload: mod_http_upload
```

However, when I restart the service, I can see in the log `/var/log/ejabberd/error.log`:

```
2019-11-11 13:47:06.923 [error] <0.379.0>@ejabberd_listener:validate_module_option:604 ignoring listen option 'request_handlers' with invalid value: [{upload,mod_http_upload}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading configuration examples from the online documentation, which documents the latest released ejabberd version, 19.09.

And you are using those examples with your old ejabberd 18.01. It isn't a surprise if something goes wrong.

In this case, the problem is in the syntax, it's easy to fix, and you can notice it if you look at the ejabberd.yml that comes as example in your ejabberd 18.01 installation:

The last line in that example configuration can be:

- new syntax `upload: mod_http_upload` if you use the new ejabberd 19.09
- old syntax `"/upload": mod_http_upload` if you use the new ejabberd 19.09
- but you can only use the old syntax `"/upload": mod_http_upload` if you use the old ejabberd 18.01

Comment: Still not working, but I don't have this error anymore, so your answer solves at least one of my issues. I mark your answer as accepted answer because my question was quite specific. I'll try to figure out the rest by myself. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed other differences between the doc and my configuration file (for the ldap part in particular), but I cannot find the documentation specific to my release.

Comment: You are right, there is no copy of the documentation for a specific ejabberd version. I'll report that to find a solution. As a quick hack, there's a copy from february 2018 in https://web.archive.org/web/20180216184324/https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/